# Running Python commands in xterm js?

Tags: terminal-emulator, xtermjs

Is is possible to execute python commands through xterm js? I want to easily print a "Hello World" statement below but not sure how to properly implement that.

```
<div id="terminal"></div>
      <script>
        var term = new Terminal();
        term.open(document.getElementById('terminal'));
        term.write(print("Hello World"))
      </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, not directly like that. xterm.js is only a visual renderer. You'd have to write a backend that actually takes the user input, runs the command (in your case in a python shell) and then tells xterm.js what to render.